# Identifying synchrony across individual time series

Tags: time-series, correlation, sequential-analysis

We are working with some time series data that look like the following:

[image]

We have three individuals (a1,a2,a3) and then several observations at regular time-intervals. Here, we have 12 time intervals.  At each interval, we have one coded behavioral variable (A, B, C or D).

What we would like to investigate is how "synchronous" or "asynchronous"  i) each pair of individuals (i.e. a1/a2; a1/a3; a2/a3) ii) all three individuals are in a given behavior.

For instance, from this dummy data it appears that for the behavior "A", a1 and a2 are commonly co-exhibiting that behavioral code.

I was thinking that perhaps some form of simple ratio of times coexpressing versus times not, given the relative base rate of each individual showing each behavior might be the way to go forward.   I am interested in any ideas of how to measure this form of 'synchrony'. (I'm also aware that synchrony may not be the most appropriate word here, but unsure what is better).

In terms of the actual data.  We could have as many as 40 replicates of these data for each group of 3 ids.  Therefore, ideally any method would be able to compare data across multiple observations, but allowing for breaks (i.e. the 1st observation of the 2nd replicate is not the 13th observation.).